# Filtering with CollectionViewSource in MVVM/XAML in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, collectionviewsource

I have 4 tables:

1. Stores => StoreID , AddressID
2. Contacts => ContactID, StoreID, DesignationID,
3. Designation => DesignationID
4. Address => AddressID

In Entity Query I used Include while getting all the details of the stores.

```
ObjectContext.Stores.Include("Address").Include("Contacts.Designation");
```

So I got all the stores with all their contacts and other objects like Address. Now I want to filter Store's contacts but our Domain Service Linq does not allow filtering with Include. It include all the data. So I want to use CollectionViewSource for filtering my child data.

In UI, I have One ListBox for Store Information and within that ListBox -> I have one more list box for store's Contacts and I want this Contacts to be filtered with some condition on its Load...

I can't figure out how to do this with MVVM or directly in XAML. But Doing it with MVVM is preferably better.

Can anyone please help me solving this problem?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get hold of the default `ICollectionView` for your source item.

You can do this like so

```
var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collectionToFilter);
```

Next, you create a filter delegate like so

```
collectionView.Filter = delegate(object item){return some boolean expression;};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In Silverlight - there is no  GetDefaultView method. Is there any good example which allows Filtering in ViewModel in Silverlight

Comment: Fair enough, sorry, was thinking in WPF... then why not create a CollectionViewSource with the source being your collection and bind to the listbox to the collectionsource.view?  You can then create a filter accordingly.